# Can I use flex to position <divs> to the left and the right inside a container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this HTML:

```
    <div class="flexBreadcrumb">
        <div>Left</div>
        <div>Left</div>
        <div>Right</div>
    </div>
```

Is there a way using flex that I can have the first two  go to the left and the third go to the right to give me something like:

```
   Left Left                                                                  Right
```

Here's the CSS I have so far:

```
    .flexBreadcrumb {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 8px 15px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, see the code below

```
<div class="flexBreadcrumb">
        <div class='left'>Left</div>
        <div class='left'>Left</div>
        <div class='right'>Right</div>
    </div>

 .flexBreadcrumb {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 8px 15px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        border-radius: 4px;
    }



.left {
   -webkit-align-self: flex-start;
   align-self: flex-start;
}

.right {
   margin-left: auto;
}
```

I have added two classes `left` and `right`,
Now what left does here is align itself to the start of the `flex` element, and there is a little tweek, you need to set the `margin-left` to `auto`, for the element on right

working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/orz06w5c/1/

Comment: Actually in chrome it seems to be buggy. Normal div works, but in a flex it renders it incorrectly at times. It seems to introduce a line break when both arabic text and english text is mixed in one sentence.